# Passing Objects as Parameters to a Function: MATLAB

Tags: function, matlab, parameter-passing

I've got a basic GUI with a button that you can press to select an export path, with some text showing what the export path selected is. As default, the text displays the current working directory until you choose a different directory.

I pass all the required variables and objects as parameters in the callback function (ExportPath).

```matlab
exportPath_Button = uibutton(exportSelection_Group, 'Position', [9 .* exportSelection_Group.Position(3) ./ 10 - 10, 5, exportSelection_Group.Position(3) ./ 10, exportSelection_Group.Position(4) - 30], 'Text', 'Select Path', 'ButtonPushedFcn', {@ExportPath, currentFolder, exportFolder, exportPath_Text});
```

```matlab
function ExportPath(~, ~, currentFolder, exportPath, exportPath_Text)
folderSelection = uigetdir(currentFolder, 'Export Folder');
switch folderSelection
    case 0
        return
    otherwise
        exportPath = folderSelection;
        exportPath_Text.Text = ['Export path: ', currentFolder];
end
end
```

How come the function will only change the function space objects, and not the base objects, despite passing the base objects directly as a parameter?

And yet in the case where I make some images visible in another function, passing the images as parameters in a callback function (as shown below), that works fine, and the images alter their visibility?

```matlab
CPU_Group = uibuttongroup(mainWindow, 'Position', [10, (uiSize - uiSize ./ 3) - 10, innerSize(1), uiSize ./ 10], 'Title', 'CPU', 'TitlePosition', 'centertop', 'SelectionChangedFcn',{@CPUSelection, amd_Image, intel_Image});
```

```matlab
function CPUSelection(~, event, AMD_Logo, Intel_Logo)
    switch event.NewValue.Text
        case "AMD"
            AMD_Logo.Visible = 'on';
            Intel_Logo.Visible = 'off';
        case "Intel"
            Intel_Logo.Visible = 'on';
            AMD_Logo.Visible = 'off';
    end
end
```

Many thanks!

Comment: MATLAB passes arguments by value always. Some objects are handle objects, they reference a resource that is not copied. Modifying a handle object actually modifies the resource pointed to. You should read the relevant sections of the MATLAB docs, they are very well written and very enlightening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your objects inheriting from `handle`? If not, then they're pass-by-value, copy on write ("CoW") objects, and your function ends up operating on a *copy* of the original object and the original object is unchanged. Have your objects inherit from `handle` if you want pass-by-reference behavior and shared mutable state.